# Why am I getting "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure." error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Using Selenium Grid, I have a hub that has one node registered to it. The Hub and Node are on different networks. These are the configurations for the `Hub` and the `Node`:
[image: configuration img1]
[image: configuration img2]

Please correct me if I am wrong, but this all looks correct to me. But the problem is that when I run my Java code (on a different computer and in a different network from the hub and node), I get this error:

```
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'NROLL97', ip: '192.168.86.31', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

The system info is correct for the machine that I am running my java project from, but I feel like it should be showing the System Info of the machine that has the remote web driver (which is an AWS Linux 2 machine) where the test will actually be ran. Since it is showing that it has a version for the remote web driver, I would think it would also tell me the System Info of the machine with the remote web driver.

The error message is almost useless; the majority of answers to this question already on SO will tell me to be sure I have the correct versions. I am certain that is not the issue, because these same versions work when I test locally.

And this is my `DriverInit` class:

```
public class DriverInit{

       public WebDriver driver;
       public ChromeOptions chromeOptions;
       public DesiredCapabilities caps;
         
       public static final String URL = "http://3.128.83.181/:4444/wd/hub";


        DriverInit(int row) throws MalformedURLException {
            // for local automated testing
//          this.chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
//          this.chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
//          String chromeDriverPath = "resources/chromedriver.exe";
//          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
//          this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
//          this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            
            
            // FOR AWS
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
             options.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.LINUX);
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();


        }
        


        public WebDriver getDriver() {
            return this.driver;
        }
        
       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the URL. `"http://3.128.83.181/:4444/wd/hub";` needed to be changed to `"http://3.128.83.181:4444/wd/hub";`